# I want to render a React Native component n number of times only

Tags: javascript, ios, reactjs, react-native, react-redux

I am creating an in app rating feature for an app built using React Native.
The in app rating library used is react native rate and is contained in its own component. I only want to call this component 3 times as to avoid annoying users. I am thinking I have to have a variable in AsyncStorage that gets added 1 everytime the component gets called.
Whats the best way to do this?

```js
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { View, Text, Button } from 'react-native';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
import Rate, { AndroidMarket } from 'react-native-rate';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage';
import remoteConfig from '@react-native-firebase/remote-config';;

const InAppRating = () => {
  const first_time_toggle = useSelector((state) => state.flow_engine.first_time);
       // TEST STATMENT GETDATA() for Asyncstorage
       const getData = async () => {
         try {
           const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem('sessions');
           if(value !== null) {
             console.log(value)
           }
         } catch (error) {
           console.log(error)
         }
       }
                   

  // Remote Config Variable
  //let IOS_RATING_SESSIONS = remoteConfig().getValue('ios_rating_sessions').asNumber();

  useEffect(() => {
    

    // Rating library Call function
    const inAppRatingToggle = () => {
      const options = {
        AppleAppID: '2193813192',
        GooglePackageName: 'com.mywebsite.myapp',
        OtherAndroidURL: 'http://www.randomappstore.com/app/47172391',
        preferredAndroidMarket: AndroidMarket.Google,
        preferInApp: true,
        openAppStoreIfInAppFails: true,
        fallbackPlatformURL: 'https://test.com',
      };
      Rate.rate(options, (success) => {
  
        if (success) {
          // this technically only tells us if the user successfully went to the Review Page. Whether they actually did anything, we do not know.
          console.log('[InAppRating] - Review Page shown to user');
        } else {
          console.log('[InAppRating] - There was an error showing the Review Page to user');
        }
  
    });

    }
    // Rating Logic 
    if(first_time_toggle == null) {
      console.log('[InAppRating] - Rating function could not be called');
     
    } else {
      inAppRatingToggle();
      console.log('[InAppRating] - Rating function called!');
    }
    
  })
    return (
      <View>
       <Text>This works!</Text>
      </View>
    );

};

export default InAppRating;
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sure there are other ways, firstly you could try vanilla JavaScript for loop like so

```
let i;
for (i = 0; i <=3; i++) {
  // your function goes here
}
```

This is the most succinct syntax that should do the job.

Alternatively, you may use the Lodash library like so

```
_.times(3, ()=>{//your function gooes here});
```

Invokes the function thrice, returning an array of the results of each invocation.  Don't forget to `npm i lodash.times`.

Here is the [link](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#times) to the documentation for _.times utility

Comment: I can post my answer, but I came up with a different solution. I just used Asyncstorage and remote config variables to manage how many times the library was called and limited the library call based on time and how many times it has been called